# Compute sum of pairwise sums of two array's columns

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

I am looking for a way to avoid the nested loops in the following snippet, where `A` and `B` are two-dimensional arrays, each of shape `(m, n)` with `m`, `n` beeing arbitray positive integers:

```
import numpy as np

m, n = 5, 2
a = randint(0, 10, (m, n))
b = randint(0, 10, (m, n))

out = np.empty((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        out[i, j] = np.sum(A[:, i] + B[:, j])
```

The above logic is roughly equivalent to

```
np.einsum('ij,ik', A, B)
```

with the exception that `einsum` computes the sum of products.

Is there a way, equivalent to `einsum`, that computes a sum of sums? Or do I have to write an extension for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) needs to perform elementwise multiplication and then it does summing (optional). <strike>As such it might not be applicable/needed to solve our case.</strike> Read on!

**Approach #1**

We can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) such that the first axes are aligned 
 and second axis are elementwise summed after extending dimensions to `3D`. Finally, we need summing along the first axis -

```
(A[:,:,None] + B[:,None,:]).sum(0)
```

**Approach #2**

We can simply do outer addition of columnar summations of each -

```
A.sum(0)[:,None] + B.sum(0)
```

**Approach #3**

And hence, bring in `einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ij->j',A)[:,None] + np.einsum('ij->j',B)
```

Comment: First approch is as slow as the nested loop. The second approach is a solution to my problem. It is even faster then approach #3.

Comment: Btw: exploiting the commutativity of sum. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [**`numpy.ufunc.outer`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), specifically here `numpy.add.outer` after summing along axis 0 as @Divakar mentioned in **#approach 2**

```
In [126]: numpy.add.outer(a.sum(0),  b.sum(0))
Out[126]: 
array([[54, 67],
       [43, 56]])
```